# DI and Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I'm attempting to refactor code that has quite a few dependencies that are relying on a static global instance.  The project is using Microsoft's DI.

A large number of objects are being created with the following:

```cs
var commandTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);

foreach (var t in commandTypes)
{
    var command = (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                
    // Logic
}
```

When attempting to add any constructor to one of the command blocks for constructor DI I get an error "no parameterless constructor defined".  An example of one of the "command" blocks I'm trying to refactor is:

```cs
public class SaveCmd: ICommand
{
   public void Execute(Person person, string[] input)
   {
      // The ICache dependency is what I'd like to pass into the command block
      Services.Instance.Cache.Update(person);
   }
}
```

Is there another way to handle the DI?  A possible workaround would be property injection, but this seems heavy handed as not all of the objects being created share the same dependencies.

Comment: "Is there another way to handle the DI?" yes, use a DI container instead.

Comment: You seem to have many `ICommand` implementations, but how do you distinguish between them? I assume you only want to execute one single implementation at the time?

Comment: There are indeed many ICommand implementations and they are distinguished with a list of Aliases and stored in a cache.  The goal would be to only have a single implementation of a command.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a great way to do this using the System.Activator to create the object.  However, based on Steven's comment above I learned that there is a Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection class that can handle this using [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ActivatorUtilities_CreateInstance_System_IServiceProvider_System_Type_System_Object___).

```cs
private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

public CommandHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
   _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

// in the for loop in the question update to use the new method
var command = (ICommand)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, t);
```

Comment: So you were actually already using MS.DI. This was unclear from your question. I feel that your solution might not be the best approach, as `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` should only be used in the rarest of circumstances, and by injecting `IServiceProvider` in your `CommandHandler` it seems you are applying the [Service Locator pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/), which exhibits considerable downsides. If you update your initial question with more context of your use case, I'd like to provide more detailed feedback and an alternative solution.

Comment: @Steven Question updated!  Can't believe I fell into that trap after having read your book.

Comment: Hi Wesley, great to see you read my book. In that case, you might be interested in re-reading chapter 10 again to see whether a design around `ICommandHandler<T>` is more suited for your situation compared to the use of the Command Pattern (which doesn't mix well with DI because the pattern promotes mixing data and behavior).